# Echo server in common lisp with cl-usocket

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying a simple echo server in common lisp (I use clisp). I've tried the example in http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Echo_server#Common_Lisp

The CLISP version (without usocket) works fine.

When I try the usocket version (with clisp) I get the following error:

*** - The condition
      CDR: :INPUT is not a list
      occurred.

Thank you in advance for your replies,
Dimitris

Comment: What's the backtrace when you get that error?   It seems pretty clear that somewhere the function CDR is getting called with something that's not a list…

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the answer, but I think this can be tracked down to **wait-for-input** and **wait-for-input-internal**.  The function **wait-for-input** has the following definition (abbreviated):

```
(defun wait-for-input (socket-or-sockets &key timeout ready-only)
  "Waits for one or more streams to become ready for reading from
the socket.  When `timeout' (a non-negative real number) is
specified, wait `timeout' seconds, or wait indefinitely when
it isn't specified.  A `timeout' value of 0 (zero) means polling. …"
  (unless (wait-list-p socket-or-sockets)
    (let ((wl (make-wait-list (if (listp socket-or-sockets)
                                  socket-or-sockets (list socket-or-sockets)))))
      (multiple-value-bind
            (socks to)
          (wait-for-input wl :timeout timeout :ready-only ready-only)
        (return-from wait-for-input
          (values (if ready-only socks socket-or-sockets) to)))))
  (let* ((start (get-internal-real-time))
         (sockets-ready 0))
    (dolist (x (wait-list-waiters socket-or-sockets))
      (when (setf (state x)
                  #+(and win32 (or sbcl ecl)) nil ; they cannot rely on LISTEN
                  #-(and win32 (or sbcl ecl))
                  (if (and (stream-usocket-p x)
                           (listen (socket-stream x)))
                      :read
                      nil))
        (incf sockets-ready)))
    ;; the internal routine is responsibe for
    ;; making sure the wait doesn't block on socket-streams of
    ;; which theready- socket isn't ready, but there's space left in the
    ;; buffer
    (wait-for-input-internal socket-or-sockets
                             :timeout (if (zerop sockets-ready) timeout 0))
    (let ((to-result (when timeout
                       (let ((elapsed (/ (- (get-internal-real-time) start)
                                         internal-time-units-per-second)))
                         (when (< elapsed timeout)
                           (- timeout elapsed))))))
      (values (if ready-only
                  (remove-if #'null (wait-list-waiters socket-or-sockets) :key #'state)
                  socket-or-sockets)
              to-result))))
```

Note that the last section calls **wait-for-input-internal** with

```
(wait-for-input-internal socket-or-sockets
                         :timeout (if (zerop sockets-ready) timeout 0))
```

Now, the name **socket-or-sockets** implies that its value may be a single socket or a list of sockets.  However, let's take a look at the definition of **wait-for-input-internal** for CLISP (it's defined in the `backend/<implementation>.lisp`):

```
(defmethod wait-for-input-internal (wait-list &key timeout)
  (with-mapped-conditions ()
    (multiple-value-bind
        (secs musecs)
        (split-timeout (or timeout 1))
      (dolist (x (wait-list-%wait wait-list))
        (setf (cdr x) :INPUT))
      (let* ((request-list (wait-list-%wait wait-list))
             (status-list (if timeout
                              (socket:socket-status request-list secs musecs)
                            (socket:socket-status request-list)))
             (sockets (wait-list-waiters wait-list)))
        (do* ((x (pop sockets) (pop sockets))
              (y (cdr (pop status-list)) (cdr (pop status-list))))
             ((null x))
          (when (member y '(T :INPUT))
            (setf (state x) :READ)))
        wait-list))))
```

There are two uses of **:INPUT** there.  It appears that each element of the wait-list is supposed to be a cons whose cdr contains some sort of state.  Perhaps **wait-for-input** is getting called with a single socket (after all, the argument name *is* **socket-or-sockets**, and when **wait-for-input-internal** is called, it's expecting a list.  That could lead to the latter getting `(<something> . :INPUT)` when expecting `((<something . :INPUT))`. I'm not sure, though.  In any case, though, the error is coming from somewhere around here.

Comment: Thank you. So it's not me doing something wrong. When i send a message with nc inside " " seems to work, but not without them.